# How to add two onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in android studion

Tags: android, share, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am creating an android app in which I have all ready added a share option to share content of the app, but I want to add another share option which will be able to share app download link (share this app), both the options use on create option menu, can anyone please tell me if it is possible to add two on create option or is there other way to add second share action.
Following is the code I have used for "share this app" action.

```
 private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "download the app");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," play.google.com ");
    return intent;
}
```

menu_main

```
<item
    android:title="Share"
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/share_this_app"
    android:title="share this app"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Comment: You can use single `onCreateOptionMenu` to create multiple option.

Comment: you can use single menu_main.xml with multiple option, make the another item with different id and implement same to share

Comment: can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: I have added two share options on my action bar with different id,  one of them is working fine, i am not just able to make work second option.

Comment: Please provide the menu_main.xml

Comment: i have just added menu_main in my main question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? Let me know if it works.

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider2;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider2 = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share_this_app).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
    mShareActionProvider2.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent2());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "download the app");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," play.google.com ");
    return intent;
}

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent2(){
    /*Your coude here*/
}
```

Comment: not working properly, as app force close after clicking on share this app option.

Comment: I did forget to declare mShareActionProvider2 (updated the code to fix that), but it wouldn't cause that problem.
Sorry, can't really help more than this right now, only when I get home

Comment: thanks man for your efforts, please let me know if you find solution.